# Why operator precedence being ignored here?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

when I run this statement

result = 2 * 3 + --num - (7 / num);

it give me runtime error rather than -1 why?
it looks like decrement executed before the parentheses!

Comment: Operator precedence is not the same as evaluation order. "It looks like decrement executed before the parentheses" It is: Java evaluates left-to-right.

Comment: In addition to what @AndyTurner has mentioned, you will get a runtime error only when `num = 1`.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do here, if num equals to zero, you can't perform 7/num operation.

Comment: @Ismail presumably that's why OP says "it give me runtime error".

Comment: I forgot to say that num =1